# How can I remove the border from input color list button?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Here is my code:

```
<input list type="color" v-model="selectedColor" @input="updateHexValue" class="">
```

And this is how it displays:

[image]

I just want the color and I do not want a border around the input button. I am currently using tailwind as well and trying to implement styling on it doesn't do anything.

Comment: The ordering and how color look it controlled by the browser, it may be not working as excepted you need to add maybe some CSS which override the default browser styles.

Comment: You may mean 'border' rather than 'order' - if so please edit your title as it's currently a bit confusing. Also, within your question, could you clarify what you want to happen. Browsers each have their own way of presenting a type="color" -are you trying to override that?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to apply css to your input, maybe this can help you,

```
<input list type="color" v-model="selectedColor" @input="updateHexValue" class="custom-color-input">
```

and here is the css,

```
.custom-color-input {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  /* Add any other styles you want */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tailwind you can `border-none` class

```html
<input class="border-none" list type="color" v-model="selectedColor" @input="updateHexValue" type="text">
```